# What happened when zookeeper sequential node run out of all numbers

Tags: apache-zookeeper, sequential

From java doc, we know,
*"actual path name of a sequential node will be the given path plus a suffix "i" where i is the current sequential number of the node. The sequence number is always fixed length of 10 digits, 0 padded. Once such a node is created, the sequential number will be incremented by one"*
I am wondering what happened when the sequential number overflow?
For example, we create a sequential node, mysequential9999999999, what's the next number?

Is there some error pop up?